# Transaction is not broadcasted on private network. Is this because there are just 1 mining node?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I'm testing a private network and encountered weird problem.
This situation may not be a problem and I felt weird because I'm newbie...

I setup 2 nodes.
Node 1: mining
Node 2: not mining but has a deployed contract

genesis block is:

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": <my id>,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "2000",
    "gasLimit": "0xffffffff",
    "alloc": {},
    "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "timestamp": "0x00",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

*Experiment 1: connect nodes*
used admin.addPeer("enode of node 1")
This worked fine. and sync completed successfully.

*Experiment 2: sending ether from node 1 to node 2*
This worked fine.
gasPrice was 100000000000

*Experiment 3: make a few contract transactions on node2 through web3*
worked fine

*Experiment 4: make a few more contract transactions on node 2 through web3*
***STOP WORKING***
These uncompleted transactions were found in ***eth.pendingTransactions***

First weird thing is exact same code suddenly stopped working.
My guess was gas price because gas price was increased to 500000000000.

*Experiment 5: resend transaction with more gas*

```
eth.resend = function (tx, gasPrice, gas) {
  if (gasPrice) {
    tx.gasPrice = gasPrice;
  }
  if (gas) {
    tx.gas = gas;
  }
  tx.data = tx.input;
  return eth.sendTransaction(tx);
};

eth.resend(eth.pendingTransactions[0], 500000000010)
```

but not worked.

*That's why I start guessing this was because the transaction on node 2 is not broadcasted to node 1.*

Experiment 6: I tried mining on node 2
When I started mining on node 2 by miner.start(1) command, these pending   transactions were processed instantly.

I could even see the transaction both on node 1 and 2.

eth.getTransaction("0xdfecfcfb8e5b36071d6bfa562fc8b6bb859b72f140ccefd01473eb4554cf221b") on node 2

```
{
  blockHash: "0x601f0eb7e97561dd012d1d4d59a8ba7952ff79252f94ac7273da57b2e5bfe0f6",
  blockNumber: 950,
  from: "0x487f5eea74ea5f3e94093d8b0501f1d2b0d5310a",
  gas: 4712388,
  gasPrice: 500000000000,
  hash: "0xdfecfcfb8e5b36071d6bfa562fc8b6bb859b72f140ccefd01473eb4554cf221b",
  input: "0x23b872dd00000000000000000000000044a70f237abc8d9fd8f8c536527481b4715c619b000000000000000000000000487f5eea74ea5f3e94093d8b0501f1d2b0d5310a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8",
  nonce: 1,
  r: "0xe153a8fb9f68d0ab139e75eac798f9244c838931a43bc5f1ef966abeb372ed02",
  s: "0x64ac48133c4bcf65e6c91a78fc244aaf4969eea8725a751522f9356dd1de5511",
  to: "0x28e79f4f21ad1cc6d2ef3c3e040dd555f785e71c",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x1b222",
  value: 0
}
```

`eth.getTransaction("0xdfecfcfb8e5b36071d6bfa562fc8b6bb859b72f140ccefd01473eb4554cf221b")` on node 1

```
{
  blockHash: "0xa52322c50e82a7cafcf2ac0b76ba688e99809783498621714bcd7b8bd806a73d",
  blockNumber: 640,
  from: "0x487f5eea74ea5f3e94093d8b0501f1d2b0d5310a",
  gas: 4712388,
  gasPrice: 500000000000,
  hash: "0xdfecfcfb8e5b36071d6bfa562fc8b6bb859b72f140ccefd01473eb4554cf221b",
  input: "0x23b872dd00000000000000000000000044a70f237abc8d9fd8f8c536527481b4715c619b000000000000000000000000487f5eea74ea5f3e94093d8b0501f1d2b0d5310a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8",
  nonce: 1,
  r: "0xe153a8fb9f68d0ab139e75eac798f9244c838931a43bc5f1ef966abeb372ed02",
  s: "0x64ac48133c4bcf65e6c91a78fc244aaf4969eea8725a751522f9356dd1de5511",
  to: "0x28e79f4f21ad1cc6d2ef3c3e040dd555f785e71c",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x1b222",
  value: 0
}
```

Looks fine at first but second weird thing is blockNumbers were different.
blockNumber on node 1 was 640. blockNumber on node 2 was 950.
***Is this even possible?***

*Experiment 6: try to send ether from node 2 to node 1*
The result was pending.
If I started mining on node2, transaction was processed but ether was never transferred.

By the way eth.blockNumber on node 1 was 901 and eth.blockNumber on node 2 was 974.
gasPrice of node 1 was 18000000000. gasPrice of node 2 was 500000000000.
So even blockNumber was not synced.

I checked transactions by  eth.getTransaction command

`eth.getTransaction("0xe51f5e0643819ceb7ceb20934f76c2db4786724814b5d474e0b33fa55061650e")` on node 2

```
{
  blockHash: "0xe703703b7bb89c3c2dfb68ac9c7f26c6374c6aa1f0ecec392c630df16f96b9e0",
  blockNumber: 949,
  from: "0xc6f974025353e8badbef519ab6081691227285c5",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 18000000000,
  hash: "0xe51f5e0643819ceb7ceb20934f76c2db4786724814b5d474e0b33fa55061650e",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 3,
  r: "0x57df9543232b4da2267b25c6e1e9c41bb1fc57d54e06bea865734ed4d9577bc6",
  s: "0x1050806ea3c07989b8f43c358f5d0d98a75eabe6db0c86a5b6f1aaaf3b60e119",
  to: "0xafce1a31f3573015b863e82e696d1734167bcce2",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x1b221",
  value: 30000000000000000000
}
```

`eth.getTransaction("0xe51f5e0643819ceb7ceb20934f76c2db4786724814b5d474e0b33fa55061650e")` on node 1

```
{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0xc6f974025353e8badbef519ab6081691227285c5",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 18000000000,
  hash: "0xe51f5e0643819ceb7ceb20934f76c2db4786724814b5d474e0b33fa55061650e",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 3,
  r: "0x57df9543232b4da2267b25c6e1e9c41bb1fc57d54e06bea865734ed4d9577bc6",
  s: "0x1050806ea3c07989b8f43c358f5d0d98a75eabe6db0c86a5b6f1aaaf3b60e119",
  to: "0xafce1a31f3573015b863e82e696d1734167bcce2",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x1b221",
  value: 30000000000000000000
}
```

Somehow I was still able to find the transaction Id on both the nodes but this time blockNumber of node 1 was null.

*Experiment 7: send ether from node 1 to node 2 again*
This time ether did not transferred successfully.

The problem looked to be syncing because both the nodes were not syncing with each other at all.

Experiment 8: restart node 2 and addPeer() again
blockNumber was synced. even blockNumber of eth.getTransaction was modified.

My question is ***is this because of change of gas price or I should run multiple mining nodes?***

Sorry for this disorganized questions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2769#issuecomment-230249342

I encountered the bug yersteday.
Having a second miner solves this issue instantly.

I was considering it was a gas issue as well. While investigating, here the best link I found on [gas price](https://medium.com/@ethgasstation/the-safe-low-gas-price-fb44fdc85b91).
I am now using only 1 wei on my private network for gas consumption (no competitors), and my 2 miners are very happy about it ! ;-)